# Is cache not getting cleared?

Tags: caching

In my content type I have a field (field_fbunique) whose default value is 0; programatically, I change its value to 1 with below code and clear cache. The value is changed to 1, but when users edit the node, the field value is displayed as 0, even thought the value in the database is 1 (as expected). However, to display it as 1, I need to clear cache manually. I have Memcached enabled.

What can I do to solve this?

```
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $node->field_fbunique['und'][0]['value'] = 1;
    field_attach_presave('node', $node);
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
    entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($nid));
    drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

In settings.php, I have the following lines related to memcache.

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
$conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

// The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

// Don't bootstrap the database when serving pages from the cache.
$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;

$conf['memcache_servers'] = array('memcached:11211' => 'default');
```

Comment: Please try to use node_save function, after that try to clear cache by cache_clear_all function in drupal 7

Comment: thanks but I just want to update only one filed not node_save , its working on my local but problem is on server where i am using memcache. I think some problem with cache_form bin.